# What are some reasons IE9 wouldn't render the css in an iFrame?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a site with an iFrame in it, and the iFrame gets almost rendered correctly.  There's just one problem -- a couple of the stylesheets don't get applied!

Confusingly, the stylesheets get applied when you go directly to the page, not in an iFrame.

WTFIE9?

Comment: WTH is the code?

Comment: Does the containing page override the stylesheets maybe? It could be that kind of rendering bug...

Comment: This is not the [brianf!ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit F12. Look at the Console tab, which will explain why your stylesheet wasn't applied. My guess is that the CSS file isn't sent with the text/css MIME-type. IE9 requires a proper MIME type for IE9 Standards Mode pages.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a doctype issue affecting frames in IE. As explained on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/ie-iframe-quirksmode/):

> If you are creating a page using HTML5 and you think there is some
>   reasonable chance that someone may embed this page on another via
>   iframe, you should use the HTML5 shim on it for all version of IE.
>
> ```
> <!--[if IE]>
> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```